# google maps embed as background covers rest of the content

Tags: html, css, google-maps

I have used google embedded maps as a background. It works fine on all browsers and devices except iPhone 6 and iPhone 7. On iPhone 6 the map covers the rest of the content
See html code below:
            
            
                
                
                    
                        
                            
                        
                    
                    
                        Data
                        Data

```
                        <div class="tabs-simple">
                            <div class="tabs">
                                <div id="data" class="tab active">
                                    <h4 class="data_title"><strong>Summary</strong></h4>
                                </div>
                                <div id="data2" class="tab">
                                    <h4 class="data_title">Data 2</h4>                          
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </center>
            </main>
        </wrapper>
    </div>
```

Comment: The `<center>` tag has been obsolete for over a decade. Do not use it. And there is no such thing as a `<wrapper>` element.

Comment: my mistake; its <div id="wrapper">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css to order what needs to show on the window first. you can possible add something like this: 
`z-index: auto|number|initial|inherit;` 
In your case if you want your `div class='tabs'` to show you can do something like this in your css file

```
div.tabs {
z-index: 999;
}
```

[You can checkout how to use it here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Comment: This actually gave me the idea... I used  
    #my_map{
      z-index:-1;
    }